# Display image stored as blob using GWT RPC

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, bigtable

I'd like to display images I've stored as Blobs in a GWT rendered page using RPC. I don't want to use a servlet because then loading the images is synchronous, and if I have many images can slow down the page load times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Servlet is the best way to serve images. Browsers *do not* block on image downloads. On the contrary, they start downloading images and other resources in parallel threads (it was earlier restricted to 2 threads, but newer browsers have relaxed that limit).